# D3: SVG not being appended to body

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I was trying to follow an example from an answering member's jsbin by using their code as a template with my own modifications. Because nothing appeared at all, I tried copying and pasting their code directly, but that also didn't work. In fact, the svg element I wanted to add to the body wasn't even appearing at all. Finally, I wrote a very very simple script to test adding an svg to the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>
svg{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",500).attr("height",300);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, even this didn't work when running it in Chrome from my laptop (from notepad++). My other much more complicated programs will run perfectly and the jsbin of this (http://jsbin.com/zeqecoge/1/edit) works as well. I'm pretty confused, and am wondering if I'm just doing something completely wrong somehow

Answer (score 2):

You are not defining a body in the code snippet you posted, more importantly, when the script in the script tag is evaluated, there doesn't exist a body tag (that it knows of)

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>
svg{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",500).attr("height",300);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I am not a html/js expert and I hope if I am wrong, someone will correct me. The behavior as a browser opens an html file is that it reads in the file from top to bottom, so when it gets to your script, you ask to select the body tag (and append etc etc) but there is no body tag that it has encountered. So the fix here is to not only add the body tag (so it exists), but also place the script within (or after) the body tag (so the computer is aware of it by the time it is evaluating your script).

Comment: So for whatever reason, I have never put anything in the body tags and my code will work fine. Why is it that in these cases I need to put my script within the body tag to work?

Comment: Does your code work fine if you're simply editing a html file? I looked at your jsbin (note: I have never used jsbin before) and it works and you don't have a body tag. BUT: I believe that is a feature of jsbin because if you export/download that project, you get a single html file with your script wrapped in a body tag just like my example

Comment: With more complex code, I've been able to have an empty body tag or to omit it entirely, and have it run fine. This very simple code works in an html file only if I put the script in the body, unlike previous files I've worked with.

Comment: Complex code is fine, but within that complex code have you ever tried to refer to or select a tag that did not exist or existed below the script tag? The culprit here is the d3.select("body"), where you attempt to select the non-existent body tag

Comment: Yes, my complex code involved `d3.select("body")` even when the body was empty or didn't exist, so you can see my confusion

Comment: Technically, you can place scripts before `body`, but you need to wait for dom ready event to be able to do anything with it.

Comment: @Oleg Is this why my more complicated scripts were okay in `head`? I did move my script to `body` as a precaution, but now it's a matter of wanting to understand what's going on.